# How to find root cause of element.style that came out of nowhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I have NO idea how this happened.

This is how my HTML code SHOULD look like:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

This is what Chrome is showing me:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" datasqstyle="{&quot;bottom&quot;:null}" datasquuid="2b7a4e8b-dd51-451e-b4ad-c25d7a088886" datasqbottom="40" style="bottom: 0px;">
```

Not sure where all that extra code came from.  The only javascript I was editing was on a different page on the site.  Wasn't even on the index page and I know it did not affect the entire site because the code was in the body of the site, not the footer or header.

```
 style="bottom: 0px;"
```

came out of nowhere and it changes from 0px to a different value as I scroll up and down.

https://collegeconnect.ph

You will see what's wrong (it's the nav menu taking up the whole site).

Not sure what file is making the nav code go crazy.  Everything was working fine until I checked the site on my mobile phone (android), realized the mobile menu button was not appearing properly (the nav menu itself was ok), then I went to chrome and turned on the mobile simulator and it started acting weird.

Comment: I don't see those `datasq*` attributes when I visit the page. Perhaps you have a browser extension installed? The full page navbar is caused by: `.container-fluid .navbar { bottom: 0px !important; }` in custom.css

Comment: yea.....weird.  But now, it shows bottom: 632px; in the code.

Comment: Whatever is injecting the `datasq*` attributes is most likely also adding the `bottom: 632px`. Try disabling any browser extensions. I can't see anything in your  javascript that would add those attributes so it is possibly something running on your machine.

Comment: Most likely not my browser.  Check the site on mobile.  Looks weird.

Comment: Most likely _is_ your browser otherwise those attributes would appear for everybody.

Comment: Does it look weird if you check on mobile?

Comment: No. It looks fine. Except for the missing menu button.

Comment: ok I just cleared my cache and it shows up fine now.  That was wierd.

Comment: Nevermind, after a few seconds, it looks weird again.

Comment: Yep; the SEOquake toolbar caused this on one of my sites too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **bottom 0px !important** from **.container-fluid .navbar** class style in your **custom.css**

`.container-fluid .navbar`
`{`
     `bottom: 0px !importtant;`
`}`

Comment: well that was weird.  ok now it shows up fine but now the code shows bottom: 632px;.  I don't have 632px in my code.

Comment: Update it on your website, so I can check from where it's coming from...

Comment: I did.  The menu shows up fine now.  but now the code says `style="bottom: 632px;"`  I'm just curious where it's coming from.

Comment: Share snap of where bottom: 632px; is showing. I didn't see it anywhere on website page...

Comment: Just cleared my cache and it shows up fine now.  Interesting.  I'm still surprised by how chrome was showing element.style for something that an actual CSS property had.

Comment: Nevermind, after a few seconds, it looks weird again.

Comment: Ok, it _seems_ to be looking fine.  I dunno.  Will update this thread if anything wierd happens but it seems to be ok.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with datasq* tags showing up in the code unexpectedly. The datasq* tags disappeared when I closed the SEOQuake toolbar for the page. Hope this helps someone.